# Wrap an image in an a tag, but only have underline on text

Tags: html, css

[My screenshot http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/240752/stars.gif](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/240752/stars.gif)

I want to have it so that only the text is underlined. The only way I can see of doing this is this:

```
.no-underline {
   text-decoration:none;
}
.underline {
  text-decoration:underline;
}

<a href="#" class="no-underline"><span class="underline">Average customer review rating</span><img src="img/five-stars.gif" alt="five stars" width="78" height="16" title="5 star review rating" /></a>
```

Is this the best way? or does someone know a leaner way? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No other solution really. Though you can shorten it a little:

```
<a href="#" class="imgLink"><span>Link Text</span> <img src="..."></a>

a.imgLink { text-decoration: none; }
a.imgLink span { text-decoration: underline; }
```

That way you only need to specify one class.

Comment: i'd do it the other way around, and put the images in a span. that way you don't have to put a span around every single link you've got.

Comment: nickf: I believe that wouldn't work. The underline from the surrounding a would still go through under the entire a content including the image. That's why you need a spanto apply the text-decoration to.

Answer (score 0):

In which browser do you have a problem with this? Most browsers do not apply text-decoration to images since it makes no sence.

othersize, just do like this:

`<a class="imgLink" href="">some text<img src="" /></a>`

```
.imgLink {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.imgLink img {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add non-underlined image badges for reusable link types, such as displaying a wikipedia-style external link arrow, try the following style:

```
a.externalLink{
    padding-right: 15px;
    background: transparent url('badge.png') no-repeat center right;
}
```

Then in your markup:

```
<a href="foo" class="externalLink">bar</a>
```